# detect if input value selected via Enter press not onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input tag

```
<input type="text" name="cOperator"  class="form-control scale-input operator"  placeholder="Enter your ID" autocomplete="off"  onkeyup="ajax_showOptions(this,'getEmp',event)" required>
```

So when I start typing in, it shows employee list. And I have a jQuery function that handles click event.

```
$( document ).on( "click",".optionDivSelected, .optionDiv",  function() {
     if($('.operator').val().length > 0){
        $('.operator-li').next().addClass('active');
        $( '.operator-li' ).find('span').addClass('hidden');
        $('.operator-value').show();
        $('.operator-value h1 span').html($('.operator').val());
        $('.operator').parents('label').hide().parents('.fieldset').next().fadeIn();
     }
});
```

function checks the value of input, hides an input, shows selected value in a div and brings to next step automatically(I don't have a next button). 
This part works perfect.
Problem is: User can just navigate with tab, choose with down or up arrows and select with Enter keypress. I have a selected value in input but it doesn't bring me to next step because Click event wasn't fired. I tried to do something like below:

```
$( document ).on( "click, keypress",".optionDivSelected, .optionDiv",  function() {console.log('someone used keyboard')});
```

but no luck. (I don't know if it's even possible to have multiple event handler)

How do I detect if user inserted value using Enter keypress and do my staff after.
it also creates me a problem when I validate input onchange. input wants to be typed not just inserted via click or enter keypress.

Please help me with this.

I can't show whole code. because it has a lot of backend staff mixed.
I'll include steps I am trying to achieve.

I start typing and I see a list:
[image: First Step]

I click one of option and I move to next step:

[image: second step]

But when I select by hitting ENTER(or return) I just see input tag with selected option, no div with selected operator no next step. Just like below:

[image: third step]

**Update:**

**Below is my workaround and is not a question**:
in combination of Aswin Ramesh's comment, alpeshandya and Vikash Mishra's answer I came up with this code and it does what I was expecting. and Most alpeshandya's answer helped me. Thank you guys.
And BTW If you see that I am somehow spagettiing the code, PLS let me know.:-)

```
     var ajaxHandler = function(){
    // $( document ).on( "click",".optionDivSelected, .optionDiv",  function() {
         if($('.operator').val().length > 0){
            $('.operator-li').next().addClass('active');
            $( '.operator-li' ).find('span').addClass('hidden');
            $('.operator-value').show();
            $('.operator-value h1 span').html($('.operator').val());
            $('.operator').parents('label').hide().parents('.fieldset').next().fadeIn();
         }
    // });
    console.log('ajaxhandler')
 };

 $( document ).on( "click",".optionDivSelected, .optionDiv",  ajaxHandler)
 $('.operator').on('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
          console.log("enter");
          event.preventDefault();
          ajaxHandler();
      }
});
```

Comment: can you try `$( document ).on( "click keyup",".optionDivSelected, .optionDiv",  function(e) {if (e.keyCode == 13) { console.log('someone used keyboard');}});`

Comment: didn't work :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a generic event handler function which can be used as handler for click as well as for key press. This should work for your usecase:

```js
var eventHandler=function(){
 if($('.operator').val().length > 0){
        $('.operator-li').next().addClass('active');
        $( '.operator-li' ).find('span').addClass('hidden');
        $('.operator-value').show();
        $('.operator-value h1 span').html($('.operator').val());
        $('.operator').parents('label').hide().parents('.fieldset').next().fadeIn();
     }  
}

$( document ).on( "click",".optionDivSelected, .optionDiv",  eventHandler)
$( document ).on( "keypress",".optionDivSelected, .optionDiv",  function(event){
 if(event.which == 13) {
          eventHandler();
      }
})
```

Here is plunker for demo:
[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4pbEKh4Ijb3f1CKTtGvS?p=info)